# Windows 7 Virtualized on Ubuntu Server

Tags: 10.10, server, virtualbox, windows-7, virtualization

I have an issue, we are moving to a production build server now. I need a virtual machine up and running on my Ubuntu 10.10 server edition. I have to setup and install various tool and plugins, on this windows 7 virtual machine as well

The problem I am facing is how do I install windows 7 on this machine ( ubuntu 10.10 server) also, how am i supposed to gain access to it in order to install tools that are required on it.

I would prefer virtual box as my tool of choice.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the problem is likely that you lack the VirtualBox GUI.

VirtualBox has a quite powerful command line. You can create your machine with:

```
VBoxManage createvm Name
```

You will need to use

```
VBoxManage modifyvm options
```

to configure the machine. You can create a virtual hd with:

```
VBoxManage createhd
```

You can read the [manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) online. It's very complete and there are even more options than using the GUI.

First, you can't use the .deb file, because it will bring Qt and all it's dependencies with it. You should use some of the alternative [install](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#id438708) options.

Finally, configure VBox virtual CD to use a Windows.iso or the server real CD and start the machine with:

```
VBoxHeadless -s MachieName
```

This will start the machine and listen for RDP connections on port 3389 (default). Just use rdesktop or a similar software from your desktop to connect to it and do all the windows install stuff.

Comment: @javier i looked into installing vbox, i got various options, which one is the correct one, for ubuntu server

Comment: Oh, yes. You will need to use the alternative installer as the deb depends on qt. It's a pity, as adding the official repo is quite a better solution. Install DKMS before, or you are going to have fun after a kernel update.

Comment: @Javier, can I get the instructions for that or least a link for them stuff :) I would like to not break the production server.

Comment: It's on the manual link on the answer. http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#id438708.

Comment: Be careful with the online manual, looks like some parts are updated for the version 4, for example, they talk about expansion packs. VBox 4 is right now in beta, and I'm expecting more restrictive licensing from oracle. If you doubt download the pdf version, I hope that it isn't autogenerated from the html.

Comment: @Javier vbox was released today. could i use ssh -x to get a gui for vbox?

Comment: Uppsss... that explains the docs changes. I haven't tried the ssh -x trick. When I'm back at work I'll try.

Comment: Note that VirutalBox 4 installation is different. RDP and other functions have been moved to an extension pack, that should be installed afterwards, kind like a firefox extension. I have no experience with it. I'll look at it today in a test machine.